# All Python Radiobuttons Filled in Even Though Using: radio_1.select?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

When I run the following code all the Radiobuttons that I have created are filled in, even though I have called the `difficulty1.select` function. I was told in a book that you could call `difficulty1.select` and then only the radio button that you wanted to be selected would be selected.

**Code:**

```
# Import Statements
from tkinter import *
import turtle
import tkinter.messagebox as box

# Windows Statements
window = Tk()
window.title("Options - CraftClash - Windows - Version 0.0.3 BETA")

# Widgets
difficultytitle = Label(window, text = "\n\nDifficulty:")
difficultyframe = Frame(window)
difficulty = StringVar()
difficulty1 = Radiobutton(difficultyframe, text = 'Easy', variable = difficulty)
difficulty2 = Radiobutton(difficultyframe, text = 'Normal', variable = difficulty)
difficulty3 = Radiobutton(difficultyframe, text = 'Hard', variable = difficulty)
difficulty1.select()

# Pack Statements
difficultytitle.pack(side = TOP)
difficulty1.pack(side = LEFT)
difficulty2.pack(side = LEFT)
difficulty3.pack(side = LEFT)
difficultyframe.pack(side = TOP)

# Sustain Window
window.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not link to code on another site. Read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have removed the link and added the code to the post. I have also made the code more concise. Thanks for the formatting help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.select()` method is meant to select (or switch on) a radio button. Before using it, you need to also first understand how the radiobuttons operates on their own when you make `variable = StringVar()`. I recommend you read this [webpage](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html) on radiobutton. Quoting a paragraph:

> You might wonder, what state is a group of radiobuttons in when the
>   control variable has never been set and the user has never clicked on
>   them? Each control variable has a default value: 0 for an IntVar, 0.0
>   for a DoubleVar, and '' for a StringVar. If one of the radiobuttons
>   has that value, that radiobutton will be set initially. If no
>   radiobutton's value option matches the value of the variable, the
>   radiobuttons will all appear to be cleared.

So in your code, values were not defined. Let's assume the 3 buttons each have different values such as `"Monday"`, `"Tuesday"` & `"Wednesday"`, respectively. Next assign some value to your StringVar variable called "difficulty". You need to use the `.set()` method on difficulty. Notice that if it's value is different to the radiobutton value, the radiobutton will not be selected. Next assuming you let `difficulty = 'Tuesday'`, you will see `difficulty2` is selected. Next if you add the command `difficulty1.select()`, you will see difficulty2&3 is deselected and 1 is selected. Make the following changes to your code and try it out.

```
# Widgets
difficultytitle = Label(window, text = "\n\nDifficulty:")
difficultyframe = Frame(window)
difficulty = StringVar()
difficulty.set('Tuesday')
difficulty1 = Radiobutton(difficultyframe, text = 'Easy', variable = difficulty,
                          value='Monday')
difficulty2 = Radiobutton(difficultyframe, text = 'Normal', variable = difficulty,
                          value='Tuesday')
difficulty3 = Radiobutton(difficultyframe, text = 'Hard', variable = difficulty,
                          value='Wednesday')
#difficulty1.select()
```

Comment: Thank you @Sun Bear ! This answers my question and will keep me from having this problem again.